# Status code 418 in Unicorn

Tags: unicorn

**Environment**: **Sitecore.NET 10.1.1**

Hi All,

We have our solution in Azure PAAS. 2 days back while deploying to one of our environments, we encountered a strange error.

Once we triggered the Unicorn for data sync, we received an error code as 418.
Please see the attached image. The error disappeared once we re-tried the sync.

I checked the documentation and the literature around the bug. Unfortunately, I could not find anything guiding me in any particular direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you have not enabled the IdentityServer configuration for Unicorn. Please enable it.

It's this file. It has extension `.disabled` by default.

https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.UI.IdentityServer.config.disabled

For more information, see https://viniciusdeschamps.com.br/solved-unicorn-issue-with-sitecore-identity/

Comment: Thanks Mark. Surprisingly it ran fine in the next attempt.